# How to copy bitmap to clipboard using the win32 API?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, bitmap, clipboard

How do I copy a buffer that would save to a ".BMP" file to the clipboard using the win32 API? I.e., I have a raw buffer of a Windows V3 Bitmap (including the header) that I can literally `write()` to a file and will result in a valid .BMP file, but I want to copy it to the clipboard instead.

On OS X, in plain C, the code would look something like this (which works as intended):

```
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
int copyBitmapToClipboard(char *bitmapBuffer, size_t buflen)
{
 PasteboardRef clipboard;
 CFDataRef data;

 if (PasteboardCreate(kPasteboardClipboard, &clipboard) != noErr) {
  return PASTE_OPEN_ERROR;
 }

 if (PasteboardClear(clipboard) != noErr) return PASTE_CLEAR_ERROR;

 data = CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, bitmapBuffer, buflen,
                                    kCFAllocatorNull);
 if (data == NULL) {
  CFRelease(clipboard);
  return PASTE_DATA_ERROR;
 }

 if (PasteboardPutItemFlavor(clipboard, 42, kUTTypeBMP, data, 0) != noErr) {
  CFRelease(data);
  CFRelease(clipboard);
  return PASTE_PASTE_ERROR;
 }

 CFRelease(data);
 CFRelease(clipboard);
 return PASTE_WE_DID_IT_YAY;
}
```

I am unsure how to accomplish this with the win32 API. This is as far as I've gotten, but it seems to silently fail (that is, the function returns with a successful error code, but when attempting to paste, the menu item is disabled).

```
#include <windows/windows.h>
int copyBitmapToClipboard(char *bitmapBuffer, size_t buflen)
{
 if (!OpenClipboard(NULL)) return PASTE_OPEN_ERROR;
 if (!EmptyClipboard()) return PASTE_CLEAR_ERROR;

 if (SetClipboardData(CF_DSPBITMAP, bitmapBuffer) == NULL) {
  CloseClipboard();
  return PASTE_PASTE_ERROR;
 }

 CloseClipboard();
 return PASTE_WE_DID_IT_YAY;
}
```

Could anyone provide some insight as to how to fix this?

### Edit

Per Aaron and martinr's suggestions, I've now modified the code to the following:

```
#include <windows/windows.h>
int copyBitmapToClipboard(char *bitmapBuffer, size_t buflen)
{
 HGLOBAL hResult;
 if (!OpenClipboard(NULL)) return PASTE_OPEN_ERROR;
 if (!EmptyClipboard()) return PASTE_CLEAR_ERROR;

 hResult = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, buflen);
 if (hResult == NULL) return PASTE_DATA_ERROR;

 memcpy(GlobalLock(hResult), bitmapBuffer, buflen);
 GlobalUnlock(hResult);

 if (SetClipboardData(CF_DSPBITMAP, hResult) == NULL) {
  CloseClipboard();
  return PASTE_PASTE_ERROR;
 }

 CloseClipboard();
 return PASTE_WE_DID_IT_YAY;
}
```

But it still has the same result. What am I doing wrong?

## Final Edit

The working code:

```
#include <windows/windows.h>
int copyBitmapToClipboard(char *bitmapBuffer, size_t buflen)
{
 HGLOBAL hResult;
 if (!OpenClipboard(NULL)) return PASTE_OPEN_ERROR;
 if (!EmptyClipboard()) return PASTE_CLEAR_ERROR;

 buflen -= sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER);
 hResult = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, buflen);
 if (hResult == NULL) return PASTE_DATA_ERROR;

 memcpy(GlobalLock(hResult), bitmapBuffer + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), buflen);
 GlobalUnlock(hResult);

 if (SetClipboardData(CF_DIB, hResult) == NULL) {
  CloseClipboard();
  return PASTE_PASTE_ERROR;
 }

 CloseClipboard();
 GlobalFree(hResult);
 return PASTE_WE_DID_IT_YAY;
}
```

Thanks, martinr!

Comment: thanks for this question and the answers.

Comment: The Final Edit code leaks hResult if SetClipboardData() fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the hMem needs to be a return value from LocalAlloc, an HMEMORY rather than a pointer.

**EDIT**

Sorry yes, GlobalAlloc with GMEM_MOVEABLE is required, not LocalAlloc.

**EDIT**

I suggest you use `CF_DIB` clipboard data format type.

DIB is the same as BMP except it is without the `BITMAPFILEHEADER`, so copy the source bytes except for the first `sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)` bytes.

**EDIT**

From OpenClipboard() documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649048(VS.85).aspx):

"If an application calls OpenClipboard with hwnd set to NULL, EmptyClipboard sets the clipboard owner to NULL; this causes SetClipboardData to fail."

You need to set up a window; even if you're not doing WM_RENDERFORMAT type stuff.

I found this a lot with Windows APIs.  I haven't used the Clipboard APIs per se but with other APIs I usually found that creating a hidden window and passing that handle to the relevant API was enough to keep it quiet.  There's usually some notes on *issues* to do with this if you're creating a window from a DLL rather than an EXE; read whatever is the latest Microsoft word about DLLs, message loops and window creation.

As regards`BITMAPINFO`, that's not the start of the stream the clipboard wants to see :- the buffer you give to SetClipboardData should start right after where the BITMAPFILEHEADER stops.

Comment: When attempting to paste data in Paint copied with CF_DIB, I receive the following two errors (one after the other): 1.) "Error getting Clipboard Data!" and 2.) "There is not enough memory or resources to complete operation. Close some programs, and then try again."

Any idea why this is?

Comment: Also, the documentation states that a CF_DIB is "a memory object containing a BITMAPINFO structure followed by the bitmap bits", which seems to contradict your description.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see I misread BITMAPFILEHEADER as BITMAPINFO. You're right.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a HANDLE to SetClipboard() (that is - memory allocated with GlobalAlloc()) rather than passing a straight pointer to your bitmap.

Comment: I've updated the example with this in mind but it still doesn't appear to work. Would you mind looking again?

Answer (score 0):

Echo Aaron and martinr.   Example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649016%28VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_Copying_Information_to_the_Clipboard), crucial section:

```
    // Allocate a global memory object for the text. 

    hglbCopy = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, 
        (cch + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    if (hglbCopy == NULL) 
    { 
        CloseClipboard(); 
        return FALSE; 
    } 

    // Lock the handle and copy the text to the buffer. 

    lptstrCopy = GlobalLock(hglbCopy); 
    memcpy(lptstrCopy, &pbox->atchLabel[ich1], 
        cch * sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    lptstrCopy[cch] = (TCHAR) 0;    // null character 
    GlobalUnlock(hglbCopy); 

    // Place the handle on the clipboard. 

    SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hglbCopy);
```

Comment: That code implies that you do not need to GlobalFree() buffers passed to SetClipboardData(), is that true?

Comment: I'm not 100% on the clipboard architecture, but I think yes: you do not call GlobalFree.  I don't think the clipboard makes a copy of the data, but uses internally the buffer you GlobalAlloc'ed.

Comment: I tried using GlobalFree() in my code and it appears to work as intended. This actually makes a big difference in my function — leaking a ".BMP" file is a BIG memory leak.

Comment: Ha!  Well, half the Internet is wrong.  "The clipboard is now responsible to GlobalFree the data, not ourselves." -- http://netez.com/2xExplorer/shellFAQ/adv_clip.html   thanks for the follow up.